# Handling 8 toggle buttons in a point-of-sale application

Tags: java, beginner, gui

I am self-taught and trying to improve my programming skills.  My project is a point-of-sale application, with lots of buttons. I am curious how improve this section of code, as I seem to be going against the DRY principle.

I have a Customer object named `cust`, and each customer has an ID that is set to one of 8 different toggle buttons.

```
    //update the sales to the customers
    //if cust1 toggle button is selected:
    if (cust1.isSelected()){
        //get the id number from the button
        cust = custDAO.getCustById(Integer.getInteger(cust1.getText()));
        //add the sales to the current value
        int sales = cust.getTotalSales();
        //set the value (note: cust.setTotalSales(cust.getTotalSales() + subtotal) doesn't work
        cust.setTotalSales(sales + subtotal);
        //update the Customer
        custDAO.updateCustomer(cust);
    }else if (cust2.isSelected()){
        cust = custDAO.getCustById(Integer.getInteger(cust2.getText()));
        int sales = cust.getTotalSales();
        cust.setTotalSales(sales + subtotal);
        custDAO.updateCustomer(cust);
    }else if (cust3.isSelected()){
        cust = custDAO.getCustById(Integer.getInteger(cust3.getText()));
        int sales = cust.getTotalSales();
        cust.setTotalSales(sales + subtotal);
        custDAO.updateCustomer(cust);
    }else if(cust4.isSelected()){
        cust = custDAO.getCustById(Integer.getInteger(cust4.getText()));
        int sales = cust.getTotalSales();
        cust.setTotalSales(sales + subtotal);
        custDAO.updateCustomer(cust);
    }else if (cust5.isSelected()){
        cust = custDAO.getCustById(Integer.getInteger(cust5.getText()));
        int sales = cust.getTotalSales();
        cust.setTotalSales(sales + subtotal);
        custDAO.updateCustomer(cust);
    }else if(cust6.isSelected()){
        cust = custDAO.getCustById(Integer.getInteger(cust6.getText()));
        int sales = cust.getTotalSales();
        cust.setTotalSales(sales + subtotal);
        custDAO.updateCustomer(cust);
    }else if(cust7.isSelected()){
        cust = custDAO.getCustById(Integer.getInteger(cust7.getText()));
        int sales = cust.getTotalSales();
        cust.setTotalSales(sales + subtotal);
        custDAO.updateCustomer(cust);
    }else if(cust8.isSelected()){
        cust = custDAO.getCustById(Integer.getInteger(cust8.getText()));
        int sales = cust.getTotalSales();
        cust.setTotalSales(sales + subtotal);
        custDAO.updateCustomer(cust);
    }else{
        //No button selected
        System.out.println("No customer selected");
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! We could probably give you more exact advice if you posted your entire method and included the code where you define `cust1` … `cust8`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short answer: You need the [Java Collections framework](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html).**

Instead of **eight** standalone variables `cust1...cust8`, you should put them into a `Collection` so that you can easily iterate through them:

```
// assuming the buttons are of JButton type
Collection<JButton> buttons = Arrays.asList(cust1, cust2, /* ... */, cust8);
for (JButton button : buttons) {
    if (button.isSelected()) {
        cust = custDAO.getCustById(Integer.getInteger(button.getText()));
        int sales = cust.getTotalSales();
        cust.setTotalSales(sales + subtotal);
        custDAO.updateCustomer(cust);
    }
}
```

**Longer answer...**

It is not known *how* these lines are being run, but you can also consider writing [event listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/index.html), which is the typical implementation for checking if buttons have selected. For example, to use an [`ActionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/actionlistener.html):

```
JButton button = new JButton();
// lambda expression below requires Java 8
button.addActionListener(actionEvent -> {
    JButton source = (JButton) actionEvent.getSource();
    // using valueOf() as getInteger() looks at System.getProperty(),
    // unless that is really the intended usage
    cust = custDAO.getCustById(Integer.valueOf(source.getText()));
    int sales = cust.getTotalSales();
    cust.setTotalSales(sales + subtotal);
    custDAO.updateCustomer(cust);
});
```

Instead of having `cust` as a method, or even class, variable, you should scope it appropriately to eliminate any possible mis-references. Also, you can consider adding a more *expressive* method `updateTotalSales(int incoming)` that returns the object itself, so that you do not have to perform that 'manually' here:

```
public Customer {

    // ...

    public Customer updateTotalSales(int incoming) {
        setTotalSales(getTotalSales() + incoming);
        return this;
    }
}
```

```
JButton button = new JButton();
button.addActionListener(actionEvent -> {
    JButton source = (JButton) actionEvent.getSource();
    Customer cust = custDAO.getCustById(Integer.valueOf(source.getText()));
    custDAO.updateCustomer(cust.updateTotalSales(subtotal));
});
```

In the unlikely (?) event that you still prefer/require the original iteration method by checking on `isSelected()`, the `Collection`-based implementation, coupled with stream-based processing, can also achieve the same outcome with the following, for simplicity:

```
// buttons from the short answer
buttons.stream().filter(JButton::isSelected).findFirst()
        .map(i -> custDAO.getCustById(Integer.valueOf(i.getText())))
        .ifPresent(cust -> custDAO.updateCustomer(cust.updateTotalSales(subtotal)));
```

- By using a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) `JButton::isSelected`, filter for the `JButton` where that is `true`.
- Use [`findFirst()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#findFirst--) to 'get' it in the form of an [`Optional`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) wrapper.
- From the `JButton` instance, [`map()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) it to the desired `Customer` object, and finally call `custDAO` to 'consume' it via the [`ifPresent(Consumer)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresent-java.util.function.Consumer-) method.